# Docker-based hosting unable to reach database

Tags: django

I am a junior developer using django as my first web development framework. During a boilerplate construction, I am not able to host and reach a postgres database using docker. The app content is available on repository https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan.

The docker daemon outputs error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution` after I run command `docker-compose build` followed by command `docker-compose run`. I use the variable `DATABASE_HOST` the same as docker service `db`. I also make sure, there is no other postgres service on current machine.

Thanks in advance for any provided help.

Comment: Seems your database host name cannot be resolved. Without any extra information it impossible to tell, we could only guess. The problem probably goes as follow: your variable DATABASE_HOST contains a name that is not known on the running environment : bad service name, bad DN, DNS failure who knows? Ensure your DB is sharing the same network than your project, check service name is correctly spelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using restricted characters in your Django secret key, and it's causing issues with your docker-compose file.

I opened a PR -> https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan/pull/29